# POST request in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, nsurlsession

I'm trying to get response from a web service using a post request in Swift. But I'm getting "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format" error. Following is the code:

```
let dict = ["UserName": "2222211111",
                        "Password": "123456",
                        "AppName": "xyz"]
                as [String: Any]

            //create the session object
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let url = "someurl.svc/somefunction"

            //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

            do {
                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)

            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

            //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

                guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }

                do {
                    //create json object from data
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                        print(json)
                    }

                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
```

I've even used third party libraries like Alamofire, Networking etc. From those libraries I'm getting code 3840, invalid response around character 3.
But I'm getting proper response using Objective-C code or by using Postman Software.
Can someone please help me out here.
Thanks

Comment: did you try alamofire?

Comment: The response you are getting back might not be in a valid JSON format. Try printing out the response before trying to serialise it. That would be a good start.

Comment: add what response you are getting. Postman resolves many issues at its own level, so it isn't necessary that api working on Postman will work on app.

Comment: Apart from the issue do not send **pretty printed** data to the server. The server doesn't care for aesthetics.

Comment: i think you are getting wrong valid Json format so need to improve from server side

Comment: try to pass this content type : "text/html; charset=UTF-8";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is example of Alamofire POST api call with params; content-type and accept headers, try this.

```
func performPOSTLogin() -> Void {
        var parameters = [String:String]()
        parameters["email"] = "p@p.com"
        parameters["password"] = "abcd1234"

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "sxfsdfsdfsfsfsf", "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type" :"application/json"]

        Alamofire.request("http://domainname/folder/folder/folder/apiname/", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

            // original URL request
            print("Request is :",response.request!)

            // HTTP URL response --> header and status code
            print("Response received is :",response.response!)

            // server data : example 267 bytes
            print("Response data is :",response.data!)

            // result of response serialization : SUCCESS / FAILURE
            print("Response result is :",response.result)

            debugPrint("Debug Print :", response)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Got the response using this. Just one correction here I removed the slach(/) after apiname. Using slash was resulting in failure of api call.

Comment: Can I know why "Authorization" key is there in "HTTPHeaders". I didn't included it in my code.

Comment: Slash need is dependent on web api implementation, same for Authorization header it was a key what is to be mandatorily sent in all api calls. Basically server api configuration. Glad it worked for you !

Comment: Got that. Thanks Priyal. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
   func postData(_ params : Dictionary<String, String>?,contenturl:String,postCompleted : @escaping (_ jsonDict:NSDictionary, _ msg: NSInteger) -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: contenturl)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    if(params != nil){
        request.httpBody =  self.getParam(params! as NSDictionary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    }
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(data == nil){
           // do something
        }else{
            _ = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    postCompleted(parseJSON, (parseJSON["response_code"] as? NSInteger)!)
                }
            }catch{
                print("Failure")
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

 func getParam(_ params: NSDictionary) -> NSString{
    var passparam : NSString!
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data
        let theJSONText = NSString(data: jsonData,
                                   encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)
        passparam = theJSONText!
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("getParam() \(error)")
        passparam = ""
    }
    print("getParam() \(passparam!)")
    return passparam
}
```

Comment: Do not use `NSString` and `NSDictionary` in Swift. According to your nickname you should know that.

Comment: Plus 1 for not using a third-party package, specifically.